# Twig & Nunjucks Problems

Tags: php, html, twig, nunjucks

I'm new to programming, I'm using PHP for the backend and learning MVC, may I know if we are using Twig, do we still need a front end template engine like Nunjucks? As I know Nunjucks is template engine for frontend, but when do we need Nunjucks when using Twig? Or why use Twig when using Nunjucks?

So I'm wondering, when we need to use Nunjucks and when we need to use twig, in developing a website including database, which template engine should we use?

Comment: Front end and back end templating are completely different. Back end templating is rendered on the server and only returns generated HTML to the front end. Front end templating is usually used to handle changes on the front end, without needing to reload the page. If you should use both depends on your needs, which we can't answer.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson So lets say for example, when we apply MVC design pattern, we retrieve some data from database in the controller class, we should render the data to the view right? And view is using Twig, then how we connect the view to the frontend part? I'm sry that this might sound a stupid question but I'm quite confusing about this.

Comment: Like I said, it depends on the application. If you only want to render a default HTML-page with no real content and then generate all the content using Ajax and front end templating (like an SPA), then no, you probably don't need twig. But if you want to render HTML with content/layouts through PHP, they twig is good to use. The same goes for front end. If you don't need to change the HTML in front end (like no ajax calls), don't use front end templatingm but if you want to render HTML and layouts in JS (fetching data using Ajax or similar), use front end templating.

Comment: If you want a hybrid of both, use both. Those two aren't necessarily mutually exclusive. It depends on your needs. But if you don't _need_ a templating engine for something, don't use one.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Much more clearer now! Much appreciate for your explanation

Answer (score 0):

For basic essential applications, you don't need Nunjucks.

PHP + Twig is fine.

In this case, your templates will be rendered server-side processed by PHP+twig and the result sent to the browser. For example an application where a user sees an invoice. Your PHP gets the invoice data from the model and stored them in variables. This data is passed to twig and the HTML is rendered. Then the PHP sends a web-page to the browser.

In some cases you may need to render cliend-side. For example you have a company selling cars and you have sales agents with a dozen of templates stored in the Google Drive. And you want to format outgoing emails that need manual revision so they cannot be sent automatically, but you want to provide the agents with some automation.

You could build a web page with three big squares. In the one in the left they copy-paste the template they have been provided by the marketing team thru the Google Drive. They enter in drive, copy the template, go to your application, paste the template. In the center they fill-in some structured data (JSON, YAML, etc.) and in the right they get some formatted output ready to copy-paste-modify-send.

In this case although you could send the data to the server to be processed, the UX experience will be significantly better if the rendering is done in the frontend side in javascript. This would be an excelent use case for Nunjuck.

In short, for simplicity:

```
Backend  = PHP = Twig
Frontend = JS  = Nunjucks
```

Unless you have a frontend-specific requirement, you can safely go with PHP+twig for several years.